# Error al instalar driver de red en linux

Tags: linux, red, drive

Actualmente tengo instalado Deepin versión 20 y kernel `5.4.50 amd64` junto a Windows.

Descargué la versión anterior del controlador de red **r8168** que es la que intento instalar debido a que la versión actual de mi controlador de red **r8169** trae algunos problemas.

Extraje los archivos del controlador y siguiendo los pasos del README.md llegó la parte de ejecutar el comando `sudo ./autorun.sh` aparece el siguiente mensaje `*** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo ***`

[image: captura]

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no parece ajustarse a lo definido en [ask]

Comment: estas usando un pc con ARM???, alli tienes un problema pero de driver al parecer, no estas usando el adecuado

Comment: Estoy usando amd , y si el problema es exactamente de driver

Comment: Para hacerlo manualmente, debes instalar primero el paquete [DKMS](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/dkms) y después el controlador [r8168-dkms](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/r8168-dkms) que automáticamente remplazará el actual. O puedes instalar [Synaptic Package Manager](https://deepinenespañol.org/wiki/synaptic/) e instalar desde ahí ambos paquetes.

Comment: Si fue exactamente eso , ya logré instalar el controlador , gracias